# NSAttributedString end of first line indent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to have the first line in an `NSAttributedString` for a `UITextView` indented from the right side on the first line.

So the `firstLineHeadIndent` in `NSParagraphStyle` will indent the first line from the left.  I want to do the same thing but from the right in my `UITextView`.

Here's a screenshot of how I want the text to wrap.
[image]

Comment: The right margin is for the whole text? If yes, you should have a look at `tailIndent` of `NSParagraphStyle`

Comment: No just the first line in the text.

Comment: I'd suggest two `NSParagraphStyle` so. One for the first line (with `firstLineHeadIndent` and a `tailIndent`, and the second one for the rest of the text. But will the first line always be a "first line" with a `\n`, or not? If not, you have to know the range of the first line as displayed.

Comment: It's a wrapping line which is what firstLineHeadIndent indents.  I want to do the same thing but from the right side.

Comment: Could you edit your question a show what you want and your actual code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Setting Text Margins article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/SetTextMargins.html) from the Text System User Interface Layer Programming Guide has this figure:

[image]

As you can see, there's no built-in mechanism to have a first line tail indent.

However, `NSTextContainer` has a property `exclusionPaths` which represents parts of its rectangular area from which text should be excluded. So, you could add a path for the upper-right corner to prevent text from going there.

```
UIBezierPath* path = /* compute path for upper-right portion that you want to exclude */;
NSMutableArray* paths = [textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths mutableCopy];
[paths addObject:path];
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = paths;
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to right-align exclusion paths?  My text view can change sizes.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. You'll need to monitor your view for changes in its width and remove the exclusion path you added, recompute a new one, and add it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to create 2 different `NSParagraphStyle`: one specific for the first line and the second one for the rest of the text.

```
    //Creating first Line Paragraph Style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *firstLineStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[firstLineStyle setFirstLineHeadIndent:10];
[firstLineStyle setTailIndent:200]; //Note that according to the doc, it's in point, and go from the origin text (left for most case) to the end, it's more a length that a "margin" (from right) that's why I put a "high value"
    //Read there: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableParagraphStyle/tailIndent

    //Creating Rest of Text Paragraph Style
NSMutableParagraphStyle *restOfTextStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[restOfTextStyle setAlignement:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
//Other settings if needed

    //Creating the NSAttributedString
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:originalString];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:firstLineStyle range:rangeOfFirstLine];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                         value:restOfTextStyle
                         range:NSMakeRange(rangeOfFirstLine.location+rangeOfFirstLine.length,
                                           [originalString length]-(rangeOfFirstLine.location+rangeOfFirstLine.length))];

    //Setting the NSAttributedString to your UITextView
[yourTextView setAttributedText:attributedString];
```