# UITextView indentation with text styling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I am using selectable UITextview to display my multiline message, i need to output my message in below style.

[image]

I can able to add numbering based on the newline character(\n) but the text position is starting from the beginning for remaining text, but i want **"address"** to be be start from **"Verify"** position

Comment: If you now the space, you can maybe use `NSMutableParagraphStyle` with `NSAttributedString`  or maybe use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27876241/1801544

Comment: i mean to say wrapped text should start from the position of "Verify"

Comment: You can create a sub class of UIView which contains 2 separate labels, one for the numbering, the second for the text.

Comment: Font style in second text have different font size, which leads to alignment issue

Answer (score 0):

append three blank strings at initial of address this will solve your problem easy way.. :)

```
NSString *stringA = @"address";
NSString *stringAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"   %@",stringA];
```

Comment: I guess this is not enough. It's working for a particular string, but this answer does not help to solve this problem in a more dynamic way. You have to found where to put these 3 spaces.

Comment: address is wrapped text. We need every wrapped text to start from the position of Verify